# AWS Cloudfront createInvalidation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am attempting to perform CloudFront invalidation using the following code:

```
var cloudfront = new AWS.CloudFront({s3BucketEndpoint: <String Bucketname>});
        var params = {
            DistributionId: <String ID>,
            InvalidationBatch: {
                CallerReference: 'Cloudfront Invalidation',
                Paths: {
                    Quantity: 1,
                    Items: [
                        '/*'
                    ]
                }
            }
        };
        cloudfront.createInvalidation(params, function(err, data){
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else     console.log(data);           // successful response
        });
```

However, I get no response in my `createInvalidation` function from err or data. The documentation for the AWS SDK states you should get a positive/negative response, but nothing is returned and no invalidation is performed.

Answer (score 3):

It might be your `CallerReference`, in the [JavaScript aws-sdk docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront.html#createInvalidation-property) (docs.aws.amazon.com) it says that it needs to uniquely identify the invalidation request.

I stumbled upon this question trying to do the same thing as you're doing and I was able to get the `createInvalidation` working with the following code:

```
var cloudfront = new AWS.CloudFront();

var params = {
  DistributionId: <String ID>,
  InvalidationBatch: {
    CallerReference: Date.now().toString(),
    Paths: {
      Quantity: 1,
      Items: [
        '/*'
      ]
    }
  }
};

cloudfront.createInvalidation(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
  else     console.log('Data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

The use of the `Date.now().toString()` gives a timestamp string that will be unique to when this code is run.

With the above code, I got an output of (after pretty formatting the json):

```
Data: {
  "Location": "https://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/2017-03-25/distribution/<String ID>/invalidation/<String ID>",
  "Invalidation": {
    "Id": "<String ID>",
    "Status": "InProgress",
    "CreateTime": "<Timestamp>",
    "InvalidationBatch": {
      "Paths": {
        "Quantity": 1,
        "Items": [
          "/*"
        ]
      },
      "CallerReference": "<Timestamp>"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter "callerreference" must be unique, which allows awss3 to avoid you submitting the same request and can be used as a key timestamp